# Why these lines cannot operate in an string

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

```
txtBeautified.Text.Remove(txtBeautified.Text.LastIndexOf(","), 1)
```

i want to find the last index of "," in my text and then remove that , but it is not working. Any Idea? txtBeautified is a richtextbox.

Comment: We need more details. Show us more code. This should be working fine. `.Remove()` returns the correct string. Has to be a problem with your `txtBeautified.Text` value or the way you are assigning it.

Comment: to add to your answers, check the signature of Remove, it returns a string - this is a new string with the value removed. The original string is unchanged.

Comment: 1 rep + username aaaaaaaaaaaa = likely got answer, moved on never to be heard from again.

Comment: @Chevex 1 rep + username aaaaaaaaaaaa = very clear question, both in formatting and content, relevant code (but nothing more), got three good answers with lots of upvotes, and promptly accepted the highest voted answer. I fail to see the issue.

Comment: He hadn't accepted at the time of my comment. So promptly, no. And his question was not clear in that we did not know the value of `txtBeautified.Text`, hence asking for more details. But all is well now and I was just being facetious anyway. You can unbunch the undergarments now.

Comment: Guys, relax! I am the user faulty orc but I am not on my computer and I forgot my pass so that's why I am with that freaky username

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you retrieving the result of the operation?

```
value = txtBeautified.Text.Remove(txtBeautified.Text.LastIndexOf(","), 1)
```

If you are changing the value of the text box, you need to assign the result back to the text box:

```
txtBeautified.Text = txtBeautified.Text.Remove(txtBeautified.Text.LastIndexOf(","), 1)
```

Explanation: Strings cannot be changed. Functions that operate on strings do not change the strings, but return new strings. Therefore, the Remove function returns a string representing the result. To make use of this string, you will need to assign it to a variable/property or pass it into another function call.

Comment: Explanation: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesvbcs/thread/bb616ec1-5d53-4b91-8cb0-b11498b7c07a

Answer (score 5):

Remove is a function. call should be:

```
txtBeautified.Text = txtBeautified.Text.Remove(txtBeautified.Text.LastIndexOf(","), 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that a string is immutable, so the `Remove` function returns you a new string. You'd need to reassign that new string back to the text box, like:

```
txtBeautified.Text = txtBeautified.Text.Remove(txtBeautified.Text.LastIndexOf(","), 1);
```